# 1980s movie or TV show with killer seaweed in a lake

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Trying to identify a movie or TV show that I briefly caught a glimpse of in the early to mid 80s.

The scenes I recall were:

- boys in a lake throwing a football, seaweed or green thing is shown floating around. Several shots later one boy is gone.
- Second scene was a girl is 1 piece swimsuit in inner tube floating in lake. A scene later we see the green seaweed stuff pull her down the center of the tube.
- Last scene was some dude dropping toxic waste barrels (or equivalent) into the lake.

For the longest time I haven’t not been able to find anything on it. I am not sure if it was a movie or a TV episode or some short that was played during a movie.

Comment: Where did you see it?  Was it on a regular broadcast TV channel, cable, etc.?  What country and language?

Comment: There is some resemblance to the segment of *Creepshow 2* called "The Raft", but not close enough to write an answer.

Comment: I haven't seen Creepshow 2 but there's a Stephen King short story "The Raft". Not similar enough for the movie/TV show to be based on it.

Comment: @tgdavies the part of Creepshow 2 I mentioned is based on the King story.